# Make event listener work on inserted HTML button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I make my event listener work on inserted HTML?

I insert 
`<li id="test">Titre : test<input type="button" id="del" value="X"><br>Texte : </li>` 
on my list, but my event listener only works on the button named "work", which is created in the HTML page.

I want to call the function `clickHandlerRem` by clicking on the new button in the list.

**Image:**

[image]

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="libs/css1.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="/script1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Ajouter une note
            <input type="text" id="oTitleInput" placeholder="Entrez un titre" />
            <input type="button" id="bdel" value="Supprimer"/>
            <input type="text" id="oTextInput" placeholder="Entrez une note ici" />
            <input type="button" id="binput" value="Ajouter"/>
            <div class="divlist">
                <ul class="notelist" id="notelist">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
        <input type="button" id="del" value="work"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And my JavaScript code:**

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    addnote();
}

function clickHandlerDel(e) {
    var oTitle = document.getElementById("oTitleInput").value;
    delnote(oTitle);
    document.getElementById("oTitleInput").value = '';
    document.getElementById("oTextInput").value = '';
}

function clickHandlerRem(e) {
    var oTitle = "test";
    delnote(oTitle);
}

function addnote() {
    var oTitle = document.getElementById("oTitleInput").value;
    document.getElementById("oTitleInput").value = '';
    var oText = document.getElementById("oTextInput").value;
    document.getElementById("oTextInput").value = '';
    localStorage.setItem(oTitle, oText);
    affnote();
}

function affnote() {
    var node = document.getElementById("notelist");
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        var value = localStorage[key];
        var html = "<li id=\"" + key + "\">Titre : " + key + "\<input type=\"button\" id=\"del\" value=\"X\"\/\><br />Texte : " + value + "</li>";
        document.querySelector('#notelist').innerHTML += html;
    }
}

function delnote(keyname) {
    localStorage.removeItem(keyname);
    affnote();
}

function main() {
    affnote();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelector('#binput').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    document.querySelector('#bdel').addEventListener('click', clickHandlerDel);
    document.querySelector('#del').addEventListener('click', clickHandlerRem);
    main();
});
```

Comment: Post the code here. Just copy/paste it in, select it and click the code format button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript will not reattach event handlers after you create a new DOM element. You will have to add the event handler to your new element manually:

Run

```
document.querySelector('#del').addEventListener('click', clickHandlerRem);
```

at the end of `affnote()`.

Comment: I have another problem, do you know how to make my "document.querySelector('#del').addEventListener('click', clickHandlerRem);" be effective for all button i generate on my list (with id "del") ?

Comment: @Otto Use [`querySelectorAll()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) to match all elements, then loop through each of them and attach the event listener.